# Qt QProcess::execute command, in Windows cmd.exe, gives -2 exit code

Tags: qt, batch-file, qprocess

I'm trying to invoke the Windows On-Screen Keyboard with the command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe
```

Running this command from Windows cmd.exe works perfectly fine.

But when I run from with the Qt application

```
int exitCode = QProcess::execute( "c:/Windows/System32/osk.exe");
```

The exit code is `-2`.

I have also tried to wrap this within a Windows bat script and execute those as follows:

```
int exitCode = QProcess::execute( "cmd /c \"w:/scripts/myscript.bat\"");
```

And `myscript.bat` has:

```
c:\Windows\System32\osk.exe
```

But this gives:

```
'c:\Windows\System32\osk.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

Comment: Most likely you have a 32bit QT application trying to run the 64bit osk.exe file. As there is no 32bit `osk.exe` application on a 64bit OS, you will need to create and use a 64bit application to run your 64bit process, or somehow try to disable the Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection function.

Answer (score 1):

`int exitCode = QProcess::execute("c:'\'Windows'\'System32'\'osk.exe");`